# CloudPage's default Page State

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

After creating and publishing a **new Page State** of a CloudPage, when I try to access the CloudPage from the Collection's page, it **opens** the **first Page State and ignores the published one**.

I believe it should open the published Page State, otherwise, it creates confusion.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite a dangerous bug, as it makes it very likely to edit (and publish) the wrong Page State.

The only workaround I've found is to always open Cloud Pages by clicking the cog icon, as this leads straight to the "Page Properties"-screen, where you can select the published Page State.

[image: Screenshot showing how the cog icon leads to the CloudPage page properties screen]

Hopefully this will be fixed with the (still pending) [move to CloudPage folders](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2024_spring_cloudpages_folders.htm&type=5) from the Spring '24 release.